# How to send an email if autosys box is running from previous scheduled run at the time of next scheduled run

Tags: autosys

i have an autosys box which runs at 7AM and 8AM daily. I understand that if 7AM execution does not finish till 8AM, My box will not be triggered at 8AM again.

I need to send an email from autosys to business stating that previous job is already running that is why next execution is not happening at 8AM. How can i do that? Please try to give the JIL file for it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how have you licensed Autosys CA schedulers for your project. In our firm, we have configuration setup wherein if an Autosys job fails/terminates/maxruns/etc., it creates high severity incident.

Coming to your query, there's no straight forward way that i am aware of. First, normally we do not schedule same job in frequent intervals, unless it is a reporting job.

Still, if you want the job to generate some sort of alert if first execution exceeds start time of second execution, then you can add max_run_alarm or term_run_time in your JIL as per requirement and set it for 60 min since that's the interval between two executions.

Here is what i have added my script JIL for a data loader job :

```
max_run_alarm: 150
alarm_if_fail: y
alarm_if_terminated: y
box_terminator: y
term_run_time: 780
```

Which parameter you want to use will depend on your requirement. If you want to kill the first job then use term_run_time parameter so that second execution "might" start or use max_run_alarm parameter if you just want to send a MAX ALARM notification.

I use both! Hope this was useful.